# How can I use config-set to "unset" the value of a variable?

Tags: drush, configuration

I am trying to use `config-set` to "unset" a variable.  In this case, I have a media image field that has required crop types on it, which is breaking my behat tests, so I want to use drush to temporarily disable the requirement during the behat tests.

I tried something like this:

`drush -y config-set core.entity_form_display.media.image.default content.field_media_image.settings.crop_types_required ''`

But this breaks the config.  What's the correct way to "unset" a config value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `config-delete`, not `config-set`:

`drush -y config-delete core.entity_form_display.media.image.default content.field_media_image.settings.crop_types_required`

Despite the name, `config-delete` does not delete any of your config `.yml` files; it only "deletes" the config inside the database.